# What would be the time complexity of the following code snippet?

Tags: time-complexity

```
int k = 0;
for (i = 0; k < n; i++){
    k = k + i;
}
```

I think that the time complexity of the above code should be O(n^2) as during the n(th) iteration, the value of k would be n(n + 1)/2, resulting in O(n^2) time complexity. Am I wrong here?

Comment: How many updates to `i` does it take for the condition `k < n` to fail?

Comment: The value of `k` after the code runs is not directly relevant.  What matters is how the number of operations required scales with `n`.  Since the `i` you add to `k` in the loop gets bigger as you go, you'll need fewer than `n` iterations -- slightly fewer for small `n`, much fewer for large `n`.  It's less than O(n), never mind O(n^2).

Answer (score 2):

Let `[i(t), k(t)]` be the state at the loop condition of the iteration t.

`i(0)=0, k(0)=0` and `i(t+1) =i(t)+1; k(t+1) = k(t)+i(t)+1`

Resolving i gives `i(t)=t` and `k(t+1) = k(t)+t+1` is resolved to `k(t)=t*(t+1)/2`

Finding the time complexity is finding t from which k(t)>=n i.e t²+t>=2n
i.e (t+1/2)²>=1/4 + 2n i.e t >= sqrt(1/4+2n) -1/2

So the complexity is O(sqrt(n))

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky one and I'm not sure* what the exact time complexity is, but I'll make a lazy approximation and provide the information I can establish.

`k` increases following the [triangular number](https://oeis.org/A000217) pattern: `[0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45...]`.

A `k *= 2` pattern in the loop would be a classical example of a slow logarithmic growth rate.

However, because we're looking at a `+=` rather than a `*=`, the growth increases faster than logarithmic.

On the other hand, `+= 1` would be classically linear, and this is growing much slower than that because the right-hand side variable increases triangularly per step.

Here's some code to help get a feel for the growth:

```js
const fn = n => {
  let k = 0;

  for (var i = 0; k < n; i++) {
    k += i;
  }

  return i;
};

for (let n = 0; n < 12; n++) {
  console.log(
    `n=${10**n}, steps=${fn(10**n)}, log2=${Math.round(Math.log2(10**n))}`
  );
}
```

It's definitely not quadratic and somewhere between log and linear, closer to log.

---

* Update: [Ahmed's sqrt(n)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73075163/6243352) looks correct:

```js
const fn = n => {
  let k = 0;

  for (var i = 0; k < n; i++) {
    k += i;
  }

  return i;
};

for (let n = 0; n < 12; n++) {
  console.log(
    `n=${10**n}, steps=${fn(10**n)}, sqrt=${Math.round(Math.sqrt(10**n))}`
  );
}
```